# Compile-time error: found "$" instead of "}"

Tags: xquery, nonetype

I am supposed to write an XQuery using the structure that was given to me. However, I have an error that I am not sure how to solve and would like to seek advise.

This is the query that I have worked out:

```
<products>
FOR $y IN db/sells/row
         $x IN db/products/row[pid = $y/pid]
RETURN <product>
                    <name>{$x/name}</name>
                    <price>{$x/price}</price>
                    <description>{$y/description}</description>
                </product>
</products>
```

The row that the error highlighted was:

```
FOR $y IN db/sells/row
```

and I have an error that states expected "}", found "$"

Comment: this is the structure that was given to me:
```<db>
<products>
<row>
<pid>323</pid>
<name>gizmo</name>
<price>22.99</price>
<description>great</description>
</row>
...
</products>
<stores>
...
</stores>
<sells>
...
</sells>
</db>```

Comment: What does `$x IN db/products/row[pid = $x/pid]` mean? Should that be `$y/pid`?

Comment: ahhh yess...its supposed to be ```$y/pid``` made a mistake. Have changed that but the error remains the same

Comment: I edited you question and fixed spelling and formatting mistakes. PLease take great care when editing your question, so it is easy for people to understand the problem and in turn to answer you. Also, please never include code or data snippets as picture, as we can not simply copy&paste those.

Answer (score 1):

Keywords in XQuery have to be lower case, so "FOR", "IN", "RETURN" all have to be converted to lower-case. However, even then there are compile errors, because you need either a comma or another "for" keyword" to bind the variable `$x` to another loop.

So the following will compile:

```
<products>
  for $y in db/sells/row,
      $x in db/products/row[pid = $y/pid]
  return 
    <product>
      <name>{$x/name}</name>
      <price>{$x/price}</price>
      <description>{$y/description}</description>
      {
        for $z in db/stores/row[sid = $y/sid]
        return 
          <store>
            <name>{$z/name}</name>
            <phone>{$z/phone}</phone>
            <markup>{$y/markup}</markup>
          </store>
      }                
    </product>
 </products>
```